# How to move gameobjects from side to side?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private int SphereCount = 20;
    private float SphereSize = 10.0f;

    private Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(-4,0,0);
    private Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(4,0,0);
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < SphereCount; i++) {
            var o = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            o.tag = "Sphere";
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (SphereSize, SphereSize, SphereSize);
            o.transform.position = new Vector3 (i + 20, 1, 1);
        }


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        /*foreach (GameObject go in Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[]) {

            if (go.name == "Sphere") {
                go.transform.position =  Vector3.Lerp (pos1, pos2, Mathf.PingPong (Time.time * speed, 1.0f));
            }
        }*/ 
    }
}
```

The first thing I can't figure out is how to create the Spheres on the Terrain in more spread area with spaces between each Sphere? It's making them in specific place in a row one near the other one.

The second part is in the Update function if I will use this code I will see only one Sphere and it will move from side to side but only one. All the rest of the Spheres are gone.

Comment: for random spawn: there are many ways, none of them simple so give the minimum amount of "spread" and max complexity you accept. you can do perlin noise above/below 'n' value only to just a 'onUnitCircle' call with growing radius, etc. so it's complex and much dependent on what exactly you want. for the update question, you search for NAME while you set only TAG. of course only one sphere has the name "Sphere". if you want to move them all, why don't you parent them (as you already know: SetParent()) to an empty GO and move that one only?

Comment: @Mark i tried with new GameObject and to move it and it does working. But for some reason in the Update function when it's moving the GameObject it set every Sphere position values to something else: position {(33.9, -74.7, 39.2)} In the Start function i set the position to i + 20, 1, 1. I want in the Update function only to change the X position so it will move side to side and not the Y and Z.

Comment: Don't change then the position but the 'x' only... give a new Vector3 to go.transform.position, which has only the 'x' value altered, compared to the original position. What you do now is you update all 3 coords as you Lerp both x, y and z of the GO

Comment: @Mark i tried this: go.transform.position =  Vector3.Lerp (Mathf.PingPong (Time.time * speed, 1.0f), pos1, pos2); I changed the pos1 and pos2 to 0,0,0 . But i'm getting error : Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3' (CS1503) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: read this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html   the error comes from you have to set as [Vector3] pos1/2 = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); what you tried to do is what the error describes: you tried "Vector3variable = floatValue;", basically